# Better way to displaying data from view model using knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model with a separate hierarchy and during, say a click event, I'd like to display a modal dialog of the data from the secondary hierarchy for the "clicked" data item. To make this a little easier to follow, I have mocked up an example in jsfiddle that achieves the desired result (without a modal for simplicity), but it's done by repeating the same markup instead of modifying the data from a single group of markup.

```
var FoundingFathersViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.foundingFathers = ko.observableArray([]);
    //click
    self.detail = function(father) {
        //get the selected Founding Father's positions HTML and 
        //set the HTML of the detail div
        var html = $('#'+father.id()).html();
        $('#detail').html(html);
    };
    var mapping = $.map(data, function(item) { return new FoundingFather(item); });
    self.foundingFathers(mapping);
};
var FoundingFather = function(item) {
    this.id = ko.observable(item.id);
    this.name = ko.observable(item.name);
    this.positions = ko.observableArray(item.positions);
};
ko.applyBindings(new FoundingFathersViewModel(data));
```

The jsfiddle code simply modifies the CSS display property to display the correct detail. I'd like to think there would be a "cleaner" way to do this. Any help would be appreciated. And if there's not a more elegant solution, I'd like to know that too. 
https://jsfiddle.net/jvz6gktm/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest moving towards a `selectedItem` approach. Clicking on a president sets that one as the selected item, which is what populates the detail section.

see my updated fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jvz6gktm/5/

detail area:

```
<div id="detail" data-bind="with: selectedPresident">
  <div class="positions">
    <div data-bind="foreach: positions" class="detail">
      <h5 data-bind="html: position" />
      <h6 data-bind="html: yearsActive" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

selection:

```
self.selectedPresident = ko.observable();
self.selectPresident = function(father) {
  self.selectedPresident(father);
};
```

As a side note: if you're using knockout, don't use jQuery to go messing with the DOM, you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: Thank you. I struggled initially to get this working in my production code and finally figured out my issue was that I included the `with` block inside the parent `foreach` block. Moving the `with` block outside cleaned this right up. Thanks again.